# Getting even/odd numbers specifically with a random number generator in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, random

trying to make a random number generator using visual basic for a school project. The user would enter in 2 different values in textbox1 and textbox 2, press a button and a random number would be generated between these 2 digits (this random number would be displayed in textbox3). This was too basic for the project, so i decided to add in 2 checkboxs which, when checked would make the generated number either even or odd.

Really need some help with an algorithm that limits the random number to be even or odd. Any help is greatly appreciated! :) (checkbox1 is for making it even, checkbox2 for odd)

```
Dim answer As Integer
Dim result As Integer




Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox3.Text = answer

    If CheckBox1.Checked = False And CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
        answer = CInt(Int((TextBox2.Text * Rnd() + TextBox1.Text)))
    End If
```

^ the above code also seems to generate random numbers in a specific order, always starting from 0, any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Do Until result = 0
            result = CDec(TextBox1.Text / 2) - CInt(TextBox1.Text / 2)

        Loop
        If result = 0 Then
            answer = CInt(Int((TextBox2.Text * Rnd() + TextBox1.Text)))
        End If



    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just an observation but in Windows, the correct controls to use for the Odd/Even selector are Radio buttons, not checkboxes. Radio buttons select one of many options, checkboxes are independent and can be enabled/disabled separately. What would you do if both are ticked? or neither? a radio button avoids this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd do to solve this problem:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles Button1.Click

    'Parse the two numbers
    Dim minValue = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim maxValue = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)

    'Create a list of all possible valid numbers
    Dim values = Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue - minValue).ToArray()

    'Keep only the even numbers if selected
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        values = values.Where(Function (v) v Mod 2 = 0).ToArray()
    End If

    'Keep only the odd numbers if selected
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        values = values.Where(Function (v) v Mod 2 = 1).ToArray()
    End If

    'Check there are numbers
    If values.Length = 0 Then
        TextBox3.Text = "There no available numbers to choose."
    Else
        '`rnd` here is `System.Random` as I didn't know what `Rnd()` was.
        TextBox3.Text = values(rnd.Next(0, values.Length)).ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to generate either an even or odd number depending on which checkbox is checked, the functions would use mod to determine whether the generated number id even/odd. If it is not what you require, then it would try again until the generated number matches. For example:

```
  Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
    If chkOdd.Checked Then
        GenerateOdd()
    ElseIf chkEven.Checked Then
        GenerateEven()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GenerateOdd()
    Dim r = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 100))
    If ((r Mod 2) = 0) Then
        'r is even, generate another number and try again
        GenerateOdd()
    Else
        'r is odd we have a match
        yourTextBox.Text = r
        Return r
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Function GenerateEven()
    Dim r = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 100))
    If ((r Mod 2) = 0) Then
        'r is even, we have a match
        yourTextBox.Text = r
        Return r
    Else
        'r is odd, generate another number and try again
        GenerateEven()
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I haven't tried this but you get the point!

*Edit - the (Rnd() * 100)) is a random number between 1 and 100

Comment: Possible `StackOverflowException` :-)

Comment: Nope just tried it, it works alright!

Comment: Hey man, this looks a ton better than what i was doing, but for some reason when i try to debug the form, it just comes up with an error page saying "InvalidOperationException Was Unhandled". Also, both the end functions say that the function doesnt return a value on all paths.

Comment: See my updates - this will solve the "doesnt return a value on all paths" not sure about the IO Exception, it works fine on mine. You may have set it up differently to me

Comment: @DNKROZ You didn't understand. Say you call `GenerateEven()`. The random number is odd, so it calls `GenerateEven()` again. The random number is odd, so it calls `GenerateEven()` again. The random number is odd, so it calls `GenerateEven()` again... until your stack blows up with a `StackOverflowException`. Very very unlikely, but possible ; hence the :-)

Comment: @sloth oh okay ill give you that! haha

Comment: Probably better off getting all the odd numbers between 2 numbers, then picking one out at random.

Comment: Surely the answer to the Stack Overflow is tail recursion?